# How can i restart Nginx docker container automatically after renewing the TLS certificates?

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot, auto-renewing

I have an Nginx container for my application.
This is how service defined in the docker-compose.

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

The volume nginx directory contains configuration file and certs folder.

The TLS certs are generated manually using the following command in the host where application is deployed:

```
certbot certonly --manual --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --preferred-challenges dns -d my.app.com
```

And there is a symlink from actual letsEncrypt certs location to this host-volume location.

```
/myapp/nginx/certs# ll

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   55 Mar 12 09:47 fullchain.pem -> /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.com/fullchain.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   53 Mar 12 09:48 privkey.pem -> /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.com/privkey.pem
```

Each time the certs are expired, i regenerate the certs. (Since the certs generation was manual, i can't use certbot renew command for auto-renewal. It will give an error when i try that:)

```
Failed to renew certificate my.app.com with error: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.')
```

So, when regenerated, Certbot will renew the certs in the /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.app.com/ directory).
After that i have to restart the nginx container to take the new certs.

Is there a way to do that automatically?
Is there any hook that can be attached to certbot to do that?

Comment: `certbot certonly ... && docker restart nginx`?

Comment: @anemyte Sorry, i didn't get what you meant. If you meant that i can use the command `docker restart nginx', yes i can. But the question is if there is any hook to trigger that automatically?

Comment: From the `certbot` manpage, every option related to NGINX is related to the case when you use NGINX for validation. Since you use manual, I suppose there would be no hook since it's... manual. But you can use `&&` to make one command to be executed after another (given that the first succeed = exit code 0). That's not exactly a hook, but a way to automate things. Also, there is a better way than restarting the container. You can send USR1 signal to the NGINX process so that it reloads gracefully.

Comment: @anemyte How can i send that  USR1 signal to nginx docker container?

Comment: This is the simplest way: `docker exec <nginx_container_name> nginx -s reload`. It executes `nginx -s reload`, which sends the signal, in the NGINX container.

Comment: @anemyte. Okay, Thanks for that tip. But still the problem is how to trigger that command automatically. What if there is a setup in ubuntu that can execute a particular command (docker restart nginx) when a file is changed (certificates) ?

Comment: @anemyte Can I use this for this purpose? : https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?highlight=hook#pre-and-post-validation-hooks

Comment: I suppose it is possible but I didn't tests it. The reason I didn't mention this is that it seems to me that you need to implement your own cleanup script and put the restart logic in it. I know there are samples but there's no guarantee they won't change at some point in future and that can come up badly. That's why I supposed using md5 hashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can test if a certificate was changed with md5:

```sh
file=/path/to/the/certificate ; \
  before=$(md5sum "$file") ; \
  certbot ... ; \
  after=$(md5sum "$file"); \
  test "$before" = "$after" || docker exec ...
```

What's going on here:

1. The sequence saves current file md5 checksum into a variable called `before`.
2. Then goes the update attempt (don't forget to add the actual command).
3. After the update the certificate checksum is saved into `after` variable.
4. `test "$before" = "$after"` compares the two strings and if they do not match, this command exits with status code 1. If they do match, then the exit code is 0.
5. `||` executes whatever is after it, if the previous command exited with anything other than 0. In this case, when the checksums do not match.